# Spring security or BCrypt algorithm which one is good for accounts like project?

Tags: java, algorithm, spring-mvc

I am using spring security for hashing my password.And is it safe ,because am using spring security for first time.

my code here

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
<security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
<security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
<security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</security:http>
authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
<security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</security:http>
 <authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
<password-encoder hash="sha" />
 <user-service>
<user name="k" password="7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b" 
authorities="ROLE_USER" />
 </user-service>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

.And I havnt used bcrypt algorithm.what is your feedback for both?any recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding on to Serge's answer,

You can configure your `AuthenticationProvider` to automatically use BCrypt by declaring the password encoder bean like this:

`<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />`

and then pass a reference to this bean into your `AuthenticationProvider` like this:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
       <!-- Your actual auth provider here -->
       <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

As Serge says, BCrypt is more secure against brute forcing passwords and as an added benefit, the encoder bean can be `@Autowired` into your classes so you can programatically encode passwords when you are creating a new user for example.

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

public void createUser(User user){
    user.setPassword(encoder.encode("passwordStringHere");
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well that's an interesting questions, and in fact 2 questions because Spring Security **can** use BCrypt for password. So what have you done so long :

- you require user to have ROLE_USER only for url like /welcome*
- user may authenticate using BASIC authentication (did you notice it ?). If not authenticated, when he asks for "/welcome*" he will be asked to identify at page /login
- your user database is hard coded in your config file - ok for demo or very simple applications but you should considere using DAO or Ldap `UserDetailsService` implementations
- you use a `ShaPasswordEncoder` - Extract form SpringSecurity reference manual : *Spring Security 3.1's crypto package introduces a simpler API which encourages best-practice for password hashing. We would encourage you to use these APIs for new development and regard the classes in package org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding as legacy implementations. The DaoAuthenticationProvider can be injected with either the new or legacy PasswordEncoder types.* - This new crypto module proposes a `StandardPasswordEncoder` using multiple sha passes or if you require it an implementation based on BCrypt

My comments :

- The choice of using BCrypt or not is really yours, as BCrypt is knowned more resistent against brute force attacks, but more resources consuming.
- You protect only /welcome*' URLs. It is more common to protect everything, or at least a protected "directory" as `/protected/**` and use exceptions for what should not be. If you later add another URL it will be protected by default which is not the case in your config - IMHO it is the most serious problem in your config
- for a real application you should consider using a `UserDetailsService` implementation based on DAO or Ldap and use crypto module for password encoding

And a last remark : you wrote twice those lines so you file is broken :-)

```
authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
<security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</security:http>
```

Comment: Oh am sorry for that actually i pasted it twice by mistake.Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Serge I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389681/does-ldap-support-bcrypt-trying-to-implement-bcrypt-in-java-spring-security. Would you be able to help guide me in the right direction?